# Combobox igual a busca do Google

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, framework

Como fazer de modo que no combobox eu digite letras e retorna qualquer texto correspondente à aquelas letras que digitei.

Exemplo: 
Tenho uma lista do tipo LisItem no combobox

hi to all

hi to all my haters

hi to all of you

hi to all my friends

hi to all people

... e eu digito "people" retorna "hi to all people".

Mas só consigo fazer retornar qdo digito as primeiras letras do texto.

Atencisamente

Comment: Não conheço o comobox, ele é Web? Se sim porque não usa o autoComplete.

Comment: @Marconi  É Windows Form

Comment: @PauloHDSousa ok.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizar o [AutoComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletecustomsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) do combobox é o jeito mais simples, porém realmente só funciona para as iniciais do texto digitao.
Neste link há uma solução fazendo a pesquisa do texto na mão, no evento KeyUp, está em VB mas dá pra converter fácil.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2162/AutoComplete-ComboBox-in-VB-Net